# How can I list result from sql to html table

Tags: php, sql

So I have simple table in database: "users"

```
------------------------------------------------------
|     id    |   fname   |  sname  |  uname  |   pw   | 
------------------------------------------------------
|     1     |   John    |   Doe   |  jdoe   |  123   | 
------------------------------------------------------
|     2     |   John1   |   Doe1  |  jdoe1  |  234   | 
------------------------------------------------------
|     3     |   John2   |   Doe2  |  jdoe2  |  345   | 
------------------------------------------------------
```

etc. 
I want to make html table where i can edit these values in database.
How can print out all users user first and last names from that table?

```
$sql= mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users"); 
$result= mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
$count=count($result);
for ($x=1;$x<$count;$x++)
{
  echo $result['fname']." ".$result['sname'];
}
```

I have this kind of code to make the user list but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Try to loop while fetching data from database with `while`

```
$sql= mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users"); 
while($result= mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo $result['fname']." ".$result['sname'] . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
echo "<table><tr><td>id</td><td>fname</td><td>sname</td><td>uname</td><td>pw</td></tr>";
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users"); 
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo "<table><tr><td>".$result['id']."</td><td>".$result['fname']."</td><td>".$result['sname']."</td><td>".$result['uname']."</td><td>".$result['pw']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Anyways this is a rough example. Try never yo print HTML with a echo or print, instead of that close the PHP tag, print the HTML and open it again to avoid unnecessary server work.

Also try to use PDO to connect to the database: [**PHP PDO Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Not the ideal way but you could always change your SQL statement to this:

```
SELECT '<table>' AS x
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  '<tr><td>id</td><td>fname</td><td>' + 
  'sname</td><td>uname</td><td>pw</td></tr>'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  '<tr><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + 
  fname + '</td><td>' + 
  sname + '</td><td>' + 
  uname + '</td><td>' + 
  pw + '</td></tr>'
FROM USERS
UNION ALL
SELECT '</table>'
```